# Warning on on POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x), ...)

Tags: r, posixct

when R was throwing warning messages on this command

```
`setwd("~/Desktop/Project R")
Warning message:
In format.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x), ...) :
unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'`
```

So, I tried creating a date for this TZ by entering

```
as.POSIXct("2017-11-01 10:52", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "Asia/Kolkata")
[1] "2017-11-01 10:52:00 IST"
Warning messages:
1: In strptime(x, format, tz = tz) :
unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
2: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x, tz, ...), tz, ...) :
unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
3: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
```

but the warning messages refuses to go? Is there a solution to permanently overcome these warnings.

Comment: `as.POSIXct("2017-11-01 10:52", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "Asia/Kolkata")` works for me.

Comment: No it doesn't work @Ronak. It gives this.
`Warning messages:
1: In strptime(x, format, tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
2: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x, tz, ...), tz, ...) :
  unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
3: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'`

Comment: Some of my code has recently started generating this warning too. Haven't figured out the issue but I suspect a package has changed.

Comment: Same thing happening to me.

Answer (score 2):

I've the some issue, if your on High Sierra it seems to be a bug between OS HS and R 3.4.2 as it is said in this post https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/455 Following the instructions (until R 3.4.3 will finally release) works for me. I do:

```
Sys.setenv(TZ="Europe/Madrid")
```

Now I can load packages, and use as.POSIXct and no messages pop up. Hope it helps!