# timezone warning does not go away

Tags: r, posixct

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048864/warning-on-on-posixltas-posixltx) but remained unanswered so please **do not** mark it duplicate.
The problem is the moment you assign a time zone e.g. tz="Asia/Kolkata" - or any other timezone (*I tried a couple others and all are giving the same warnings*).

```
as.POSIXct("2017-11-01 10:52", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "Asia/Kolkata")
Warning messages:
1: In strptime(x, format, tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
2: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x, tz, ...), tz, ...) :
  unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
3: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
```

I also tried using the lubridate package:

`ymd(20171115,tz = "Asia/Kolkata")`

```
# [1] "2017-11-15 IST"
Warning messages:
1: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
2: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(lt) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
3: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(ct) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
4: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
```

Seems this has become an epidemic. Now even sourcing my code which was clean is giving dozens of warnings - all the same.

There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

```
> warnings()

Warning messages:
1: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
2: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
3: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
4: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
5: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
6: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
7: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
8: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata'
9: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/Asia/Kolkata
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Why don't you try India Standard Time as Time Pine?

Comment: This is probably system dependent. Please provide information about your OS. Also, have you checked if the problem persists in a clean, vanilla R session?

Comment: @Roland, that is a possibility. I have only yesterday upgraded my Mac to Mac OS HIGH SIERRA. I can see hundreds of files when i locate the string 'zoneinfo' on my mac command line... and i spot this is there. /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata

Comment: @MKR - i tried "IST" string but it still gives the same error.

Comment: How have you installed R? Have you tried reinstalling it (in particular, if you had installed it from source, possibly via homebrew or macports)?

Comment: Why would I reinstall R again? Unless there is no other way to fix this trvial timezone issue.

Comment: Because you did a major OS upgrade? If you installed R from source you should definitely reinstall.

Comment: I didn't install from source. It was from CRAN. Do I still reinstall R? I am a but afraid as last time I reinstalled R a lot of my packages started giving errors asking me to upgrade them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've the some issue, if your on High Sierra it seems to be a bug between OS HS and R 3.4.2 as it is said in this post https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/455 Following the instructions (until R 3.4.3 will finally release) works for me. I do:

```
Sys.setenv(TZ="Europe/Madrid")
```

Now I can load packages and no messages pop up. Hope it helps!

***Edited***

R 3.4.3 was released and the problem is fixed.

Comment: I will check it out soon

Comment: The problem was that OS Sierra New has changed the location of locale files.